# How can I add a custom item to a NavigationView with a menu layout?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I've been experimenting with simplifying some navigation drawer code by making use of the new [`NavigationView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html) class in the Android design support library. It works great if you just want icons on the left, and text on the right like in the example in the documentation, but what if I want to add a single custom view to the layout which has an `android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat` like in the Google Play Movies app (see screenshot below)?

[image: Google Play Movies]

I've tried using the `actionLayout` attribute to specify a custom layout file like in the example code below, however that attribute appeared to be ignored as it didn't work.

`res/menu/navigation_drawer.xml`

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:id="@+id/group1"
            android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_screen1"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_list_black_24dp"
            android:title="Screen 1" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_screen2"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
            android:title="Screen2"/>
    </group>
    <group  android:id="@+id/group2">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_custom"
            android:icon="@drawable/custom_icon_24dp"
            app:actionLayout="@layout/nav_drawer_switch"
            android:title="Custom item with switch"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"
            android:title="Settings"/>
    </group>
</menu>
```

`res/layout/nav_drawer_switch.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Custom item with switch"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

How can I get this to work? Ideally I'd like to add the custom view while still making use of my Menu layout, but if that's not possible without using a crude hack (like tapping into an existing layout generated by the support library) then I'd like to know the solution with the least amount of code, and which still makes it worth transitioning to `NavigationView`.

Comment: You can't customize item with the current NavigationView implementation. NavigationView use a ListView to polulate item which is a TextView and currently there are no way to customize that ListView item.

Comment: Is there a way to add 2 lines of text in menu item? I tried adding through actionLayout and it by adds to the right side instead of below. Example like Google drive-> Upgrade storage option shows 2 line of text

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The `actionLayout` attribute is [now supported in Android Support Library 23.1](http://android-developers.blogspot.jp/2015/10/android-support-library-231.html):

> NavigationView provides a convenient way to build a navigation drawer, including the ability to creating menu items using a menu XML file. We’ve expanded the functionality possible with the ability to set custom views for items via app:actionLayout or using MenuItemCompat.setActionView().

So the code in the question should just work now.

Comment: Request example of using

Comment: it should just be a matter of adding the attribute `app:actionLayout="@layout/my_switch_layout"` to a menu item. I already gave an example for what `my_switch_layout` looks like in the question

Comment: @TimRae: I tried using app:actionLayout but it didn't work. Anything else that I might be missing ?

Comment: Are you using v23.1.0 of the design support library? app:actionLayout should work, so please make a new question if you can't figure it out

Comment: how to make the actionLayout align left, right after the title?

Comment: better stick to using NavigationView as a container. I was unable to modify the size of menu items or the lateral margins.

Comment: wasted my day to figure out there is a bug in 23.0.1 :/

Comment: Give a link someone may find it useful

Comment: not useful when using in navigation view, it still puts place for icon and title even you dont specify them.

Answer (score 20):

`NavigationView` is a subclass of `FrameLayout`, which can have multiple children:

> You can, however, add multiple children to a FrameLayout and control
>   their position within the FrameLayout by assigning gravity to each
>   child, using the android:layout_gravity attribute.

That means you can add a custom view to your `NavigationView`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:menu="@menu/side_menu">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="night_mode"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately I can't find a way to set the position  of the `LinearLayout` exactly beneath the existing (library generated child layout). I presume you meant I could use `layout_gravity="bottom"` and empirically adjust the height until it looks ok, but this is not great.

Comment: this solution is like no use at all NavigationView and use just DrawerLayout, i'm wrong?

Comment: This solution is a way to add a custom view to the bottom of the NavigationView. The NavigationView is still used to the menu layout.

Comment: NavigationView is a FrameLayout which contains a ListView internally. This workaround does not allow to add custom menu items to the ListView, only to display something on top of it which is not in sync with the ListView's scroll.

Comment: Yes, you are right, this solution adds a static footer. By the way, this may help others with similar problems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30543605/how-to-add-footer-to-navigationview-android-support-design-library

Comment: how do you get onclick of that?

Comment: thanks you are safe my time. used direct id of viewfindViewById(R.id.nav_item_temp_tv).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Utility.showToast(MainActivity.this,"clikedddd");
            }
        });

Comment: In my case this is a useful approach, but the problem is that if the NavigationView menu has lots of items, some of them may get hidden by the "footer". A somewhat hacky workaround is to add empty, dummy items at the end of the menu (`<item android:title=""/>`) taking up vertical space, so that the real menu content can be scrolled into view.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem and found that `NavigationView` behaves differently depending on:

- Whether you set the `android:title` and `android:icon` attributes on `item` or not
- What kind of view your action layout contains (e.g. `TextView` or others)

Not setting the attributes worked for completely customizing the item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_custom"
        android:title="@null"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/nav_drawer_switch" />
</menu>
```

(Note that you can also just not set `android:title`, but that results in a warning in Android Studio.)

The result:

[image: navigation view with switch as custom action layout]

(This is with version 27.1.1 of `com.android.support:design`, not sure about other versions.)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Thanks for this!

Comment: This answer guided me to add extra layout elements to my menu's `item`s. In my case, adding a extra icon to the right side. Now I wonder: how can I control each item's `actionLayout` (and their children of course) attributes programatically, in my case, either to change extra icon's image or switch if it's either visible or invisible? Maybe I end up making a new question from this eventually... EDIT: Said and done, [here is my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73683267/3692177)

Answer (score 6):

create a layout with switchcompat and mention it in menu item as

```
<item android:id="@+id/notification"
        android:title="Notification"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/notify" />`
```

then notify layout add this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
    android:id="@+id/switch_compat"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:checked="false"
    android:onClick="notify"/>
```

onclick is the keyPoint,implement handler in your Activity,then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at this library: https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer. It makes it easy to use Navigation Drawer and it supports custom views.

Comment: Cool, it's not in the documentation but it seems you can easily add any of these provided views, which includes a switch :)

https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/tree/develop/library/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/materialdrawer/model

I wonder if there any forks for supporting down to SDK 8 though? :-/