# Android NavigationView item height

Tags: android

I know that it is not recommended to channge NavigationView item height.
But I need to decrease it a littl in order all items fit without scrolling.

I tried to create a style:

```
<style name="NavigationDrawerStyle">
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
        <item name="android:listPreferredItemHeight">30dp</item>
        <item name="android:listPreferredItemHeightLarge">30dp</item>
        <item name="android:listPreferredItemHeightSmall">30dp</item>
 </style>
```

And in layout add:

```
 app:theme="@style/NavigationDrawerStyle"
```

But it changes only font size and doesn't affect item height.

Comment: and i need to increase the height.

Comment: I found a tricky solution. Add to your dimens.xml   <dimen name="design_navigation_separator_vertical_padding">20dp</dimen> try different values in dp to achieve the result you want

Comment: Won`t work :(
 i have overridden design_navigation_separator_vertical_padding to 0dp in order to show the item selection background to appear edge to edge when tapped.

Comment: Then If you consider external libs, you could use https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu and you are free to customize it as you want

Comment: Not really, rather using actionLayout would be convinient i guess.
ref : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30728842/how-can-i-add-a-custom-item-to-a-navigationview-with-a-menu-layout

Comment: check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35313302/custom-menu-item-size-and-textsize-in-navigation-view) it may useful.

Answer (score 0):

If You just want to change height of Navigation item you can add below line to your style.xml file

```
 <item name="listPreferredItemHeightSmall">60dp</item>
```

if you want to change item icon or title text you can use below lines in your dimen.xml file

```
<dimen name="design_navigation_padding_top_default" tools:override="true">5dp</dimen>
<dimen name="design_navigation_separator_vertical_padding" tools:override="true">0dp</dimen>
<dimen name="design_navigation_padding_bottom" tools:override="true">5dp</dimen>
<dimen name="design_navigation_icon_size" tools:override="true">20dp</dimen>
<dimen name="design_navigation_icon_padding" tools:override="true">50dp</dimen>
```

This works for me and hope will work for you too !