# custom menu item size and textsize in navigation view

Tags: android, navigationview

I am using the code to customize height of text and row height in navigation view and it works on api21+ but the same code is not working in api 16. How can I make it work ?

COde:

Create a style and apply it to NavigationView using `app:theme`

```
<style name="NavigationViewStyle">
     <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item> <!-- menu item text size-->
     <item name="android:listPreferredItemHeightSmall">40dp</item><!-- menu item height-->
</style>
```

And then, apply this style to NavigationView using app:theme

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
       ...
       ...    
        app:theme="@style/NavigationViewStyle"
       ...
       ...


</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Comment: Note to others: this question has been answered here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35453698/listpreferreditemheightsmall-is-not-working-on-api-16

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In code you can use this code to customize text view. try this and let me know.

```
private final ArrayList<View> mMenuItems = new ArrayList<>();
    final Menu navMenu = navigationView.getMenu();
    // Install an OnGlobalLayoutListener and wait for the NavigationMenu to fully initialize
    navigationView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            // Remember to remove the installed OnGlobalLayoutListener
            navigationView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            // Loop through and find each MenuItem View
            for (int i = 0; i < navMenu.size(); i++) {
                final String id = "nav_menuItem" + (i);
                final MenuItem item = navMenu.findItem(getResources().getIdentifier(id, "id", getPackageName()));
                navigationView.findViewsWithText(mMenuItems, item.getTitle(), View.FIND_VIEWS_WITH_TEXT);
            }
            // Loop through each MenuItem View and apply your custom Typeface

            for (final View menuItem : mMenuItems) {
                ((TextView) menuItem).setTypeface(fontLight, Typeface.NORMAL);
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: how can I change text size and distance between two menu-items in navigation view ?

Comment: @jason you are getting text view now you can call setTextsize and setpadding method on it.

Answer (score 0):

Check your res/values directories, you may find a res/values-v16 directory that implements a different style

Comment: I havae vlaues,values-w820dp and values-v21. SHould I remove something?