# listPreferredItemHeightSmall is not working on api 16

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-styles, navigationview

I am using the code below and it's working fine on api 23 but not on another device on api 16(Jelly Bean) .

Style:

```
<style name="NavigationViewStyle">
     <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item> <!-- menu item text size-->
     <item name="android:listPreferredItemHeightSmall">40dp</item><!-- menu item height-->
</style>
```

And then, apply this style to NavigationView using `app:theme`

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
       ...
       ...    
        app:theme="@style/NavigationViewStyle"
       ...
       ...


</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `"android:listPreferredItemHeightSmall"` without "android" nameSpace for older versions.

Comment: Thanks so much dude. Worked for Api 19.