# Android NavigationView: reduce space between icon and text and `itemBackground` not working

Tags: android, android-navigationview

Is there a way to reduce the space between the icon and text in the NavigationView when its built using a menu xml?

I've tried to text `android:drawablePadding` using the `app:itemTextAppearance` attribute and that doesn't work, I've tried setting the padding and margins and nothing works.

Also, when I set `app:itemBackground` and set the checked state, the entire menu item doesn't highlight, I get something like the picture below.

[image]

The xml used to create the `itemBackground` is:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/white_alpha_10" />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@color/white_alpha_10" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/white_alpha_10" />
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/white_alpha_10" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

Any idea what could be going on? Clearly looks like there is a background color on the menu item, however the menu xml is pretty stock standard.

The `NavigationView` back the purple background on it set from a theme:

```
<!--Activity xml -->
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:theme="@style/AppTheme.NavigationView"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_nav_drawer"
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/nav_drawer_item"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"/>

<!-- styles.xml -->
<style name="AppTheme.NavigationView" parent="Widget.Design.NavigationView">
    <item name="android:background">@color/charcoal_new</item>
    <item name="itemIconTint">@color/nav_drawer_icon</item>
    <item name="android:listDivider">@color/dusk_alpha_50</item>
    <item name="itemTextAppearance">@style/NavigationViewTextAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="NavigationViewTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Body.Regular">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">0dp</item>
</style>
```

I'm using Android support/design library 23.2.1.

Comment: `Change sec.. Code` is item or header? If it is header show us `@layout/nav_header`

Comment: Try this link it will allow you to get textview for each row so then you can customize it. - http://stackoverflow.com/a/35313552/2128166

Comment: I managed to find the dimension resouce in the source  and override it. Just the highlight problem remains.

Comment: How did you found dimension resource and saw default values?

Comment: You need to search through the source code. I can't remember what the exact process was now, but having a read through the source code is always a good idea.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

After digging through the source. I found that you could override a dimension resource to fix this.

`<dimen tools:override="true" name="design_navigation_icon_padding">16dp</dimen>`

Beware though that this will change the dimension resource everywhere!
You may also be able to copy the layout file and override that instead `design_navigation_menu.xml`

As for the different color edges, I set `app:itemBackground="@android:color/transparent"` and then in the theme for the NavigationView set:

`<item name="selectableItemBackground">@drawable/nav_drawer_item_selector</item>`

You can handle both in the theme for your NavigationView as follows:

```
    <item name="selectableItemBackground">@drawable/nav_drawer_item_selector</item>
    <item name="itemBackground">@color/transparent</item>
```

**nav_drawer_item_selector.xml** looks like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/white_alpha_10" />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@color/white_alpha_10" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/white_alpha_10" />
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/white_alpha_10" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer the tools:override suggestion from your part helped me fixed the issue of reducing the margine of the elements within the separators by overriding <dimen tools:override="true" name="design_navigation_separator_vertical_padding">1dp</dimen>  , can you kindly mark your answer as the accepted one .

Comment: @Ali Do you still have the working example? Do you mind sharing them here. `selectableItemBackground` kills the whole layout for me. The edges causes by padding inside `NavigationMenuItemView` and setting `itemBackground` transparent doesn't seem to do anything for me.

Comment: The code above, still works for me, the difference may be somewhere else. Try creating a question on SO and provide as much detail as you can.

Comment: You also need to add xmlns:tools="http: //schemas.android.com/tools" to namespaces.

Answer (score 26):

Use `app:itemIconPadding` in new material `NavigationView`

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
                        ...
                        app:itemIconPadding="10dp"/>
```

Comment: Hey it worked for me, simple and effective. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 22):

Just add this line in **dimens.xml** file

```
<dimen tools:override="true" name="design_navigation_icon_padding">10dp</dimen>
```

this will override padding of NavigationView

Comment: It's dimens.xml , not dimen.xml

Answer (score 2):

With the [`NavigationView`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/NavigationView.md) defined in the Material Components Library use the **`app:itemIconPadding`** attribute.

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    app:itemIconPadding="4dp"
    ../>
```

[image]
[image]

You can also define a custom style like:

```
  <style name="CustomNavigationView" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.NavigationView">
    <item name="itemIconPadding">@dimen/....</item>
  </style>
```

The default value is defined by the `@dimen/mtrl_navigation_item_icon_padding` and it is `14dp`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not using Material Design, in your `.xml` file where you have included the `NavigationView` insert this code:

```
app:itemIconPadding="14dp"
```

`14dp` is an example, please choose your own suitable value.

Example:

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="175dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
    app:itemIconPadding="14dp"    <------
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
</com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case if someone doesn't know about tools, follow below 
Open `dimens.xml` in `res`->`Values`->`dimens.xml`

`<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <dimen tools:override="true" name="design_navigation_icon_padding">10dp</dimen>
</resources>`