# How to control NavigationView margin between menu items

Tags: android

I have a navigation drawer with many items so the user needs to scroll up and down in order to see all the items.

I would like to reduce the margins between individual menu items, so that all items fit within a standard screen with no need to scroll.

Is there a way to control the margins in between the menu items?

Answer (score 10):

Answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36417267/2452029) helped me to reduce space at least between groups. I used the following dimen

```
<dimen tools:override="true" name="design_navigation_separator_vertical_padding">1dp</dimen>
```

Answer (score 2):

We can create a drawable and set it as the **NavigationView's** **itemBackground** attribute. I will explain below:

If we walk through the **NavigationMenuAdapter**, we will see there are four types of items:

```
private static final int VIEW_TYPE_NORMAL = 0;
private static final int VIEW_TYPE_SUBHEADER = 1;
private static final int VIEW_TYPE_SEPARATOR = 2;
private static final int VIEW_TYPE_HEADER = 3;
```

What we want to work with is **VIEW_TYPE_NORMAL**. The attributes exposed to developers can be found in the below code:

```
case VIEW_TYPE_NORMAL:
      {
        NavigationMenuItemView itemView = (NavigationMenuItemView) holder.itemView;
        itemView.setIconTintList(iconTintList);
        if (textAppearanceSet) {
          itemView.setTextAppearance(textAppearance);
        }
        if (textColor != null) {
          itemView.setTextColor(textColor);
        }
        ViewCompat.setBackground(
            itemView,
            itemBackground != null ? itemBackground.getConstantState().newDrawable() : null);
        NavigationMenuTextItem item = (NavigationMenuTextItem) items.get(position);
        itemView.setNeedsEmptyIcon(item.needsEmptyIcon);
        itemView.setHorizontalPadding(itemHorizontalPadding);
        itemView.setIconPadding(itemIconPadding);
        if (hasCustomItemIconSize) {
          itemView.setIconSize(itemIconSize);
        }
        itemView.setMaxLines(itemMaxLines);
        itemView.initialize(item.getMenuItem(), 0);
        break;
      }
```

Unfortunately,there is no interface for us to add margins between the **NavigationMenuItemView**. However, it allows us to set a background. So we can set a customer drawable to the NavigationView with a specific height. We only set a height in that drawable, like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"android:shape="rectangle">
<size android:height="60dp"/>
</shape>
```

Then apply this drawable to the **NavigationView** in the layout.xml, like:

```
   <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/bk_menu_item"/>
```

I understand it is not a perfect solution, but it seems the only solution working in my case.

Comment: This worked for me although because I had a state based background for each item (so different colors when selected or normal) I had to change two background drawable heights to make sure the height remained constant when an item was pressed or not.

Answer (score 0):

Paste this in `styles.xml`

```
<style name="NavigationTheme" parent="AppTheme">
  <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
  <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">02dp</item>
</style>
```

In navigation drawer put this in each item:

```
android:theme="@style/NavigationTheme"
```

Comment: This is identical to USKMobility's answer posted more than a year before. It might as well be copy and pasted.

Answer (score 0):

add below code in `dimens.xml`

```
 <dimen tools:override="true" name="design_navigation_icon_padding">16dp</dimen>
```