# How to change the group text size and item ditance of navigation

Tags: android

I set the style for my drawer menu:

```
<style name="NavDrawerTextStyle" parent="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:listPreferredItemHeightSmall">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">200dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">200dp</item>
</style>
```

and set to it:

There is no changing for my drawer menu , it's still like default

How do i set the distance with item between item ?

and how do i set the text size of `group` ? I only know `<item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>` for item text

Any help would be appreciated , thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36417267/6756514

Comment: Thanks for your information , it looks like the point is `<dimen tools:override="true" name="design_navigation_icon_padding">16dp</dimen>` , but i can't figure out where should be the code position

Comment: inside your dimen.xml

Comment: @DivyeshPatel  , i got it , thank you