# excessive space between menu icon and text

Tags: java, android, toolbar

So I have a menu item which has too much space between the icon and the text.
[The image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baiVO.png)

How do I remove the space between the icon and the text?

Here is my menu.xml file:

```
<menu xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:title=""
          android:id="@+id/overflowmenu"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_more_vert_24"
          app:showAsAction="always">
        <menu>
            <item
                    android:title="Settings"
                    android:id="@+id/updateId"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"
                    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ActionBar.nameText"/>
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

I tried the solutions from [Android NavigationView: reduce space between icon and text and `itemBackground` not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36397268/android-navigationview-reduce-space-between-icon-and-text-and-itembackground) but that did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
The image size needs to be bigger like 24x24.