# NavigationView with different icon states

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-navigationview

[image: like the gray and green one here]

So is there a way in NavigationView specifically that I can make an icon that has different states changing dynamically like the picture above?

Currently Using these versions

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**
It looks like you can. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33161356).

> NavigationView provides a convenient way to build a navigation drawer,
>   including the ability to creating menu items using a menu XML file.
>   We’ve expanded the functionality possible with the ability to set
>   custom views for items via app:actionLayout or using
>   MenuItemCompat.setActionView().

**Old Answer:**

After  a quick look into the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html) and the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.java) of this View it isn't actually possible to do this.

An alternative workaround, but this is very ugly, is to give each view a background Ressource which contains the right image. But please, don't do this!

If you want to do this use the "old" way to implement the DrawerLayout layout. Put a Fragment in that which is under your control and you can design it like you want.

Comment: while it promisingly answers the question, I think I have found a library that suits my needs best. thanks. [material-drawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer)