# 2 textviews in one Navigation Menu Item (Android)

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

From this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/), I know how to make a simple navigation menu.
Now I want to make a slightly different navigation menu where one item contains two textview instead of one. Meaning the second textview will show slightly smaller size similar to the screenshots below
[image]

[image]

But how do I do that?
Does anyone has any idea?
Appreciates the advice.
Thank you

Comment: This will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30728842/how-can-i-add-a-custom-item-to-a-navigationview-with-a-menu-layout

Answer (score 1):

Drawer Layout acts just as a simple holder. You can add listview in that holder and can customise it. 
here is the tutorial for the same. You will get idea how to do it

http://www.tutecentral.com/android-custom-navigation-drawer/