# How to print a character at the edge of navigation view?

Tags: android, submenu, navigation-drawer

I have a navigation view with menu items. Some of the menu items leads to sub menus which are depicted by '>' greater than symbol. I am trying to print this '>' symbol just at the edge of navigation drawer view. Unfortunately I found no solution on how to do this. I am trying to achieve it manually by using "\t" tab with in the string but its not working. In the picture the arrows in green color shows the original position of '>' symbol. But i want to place them at the edge of navigation view shown in red circles. **HOW CAN I DO THIS?**

[image]

My xml file for the following output is drawer_menu.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:title="@string/inapp_purchases">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/buy_products"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp"
                android:title="Buy Products\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t>"/>
        </menu>
    </item>

    <item android:title="@string/Manage_Database">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/manage_database"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_import_export_black_24dp"
                android:title="Import | Export\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t>"/>
        </menu>
    </item>

    <item android:title="@string/Search">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/search_tmdb_tv"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_tv_black_24dp"
                android:title="Search TV\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t>" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/search_tmdb_movies"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_local_movies_black_24dp"
                android:title="Search Movies\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t>" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/search_database"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
                android:title="@string/Search_Database" />
        </menu>
    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/more"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_more_horiz_black_24dp"
        android:title="More\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t>" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/close"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_exit_to_app_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/close" />

</menu>
```

Comment: share your menu item xml file.

Comment: updated please check it

Comment: follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30728842/how-can-i-add-a-custom-item-to-a-navigationview-with-a-menu-layout