# NavigationView menu items with actionLayout. How can I set those action layout's attribute for each item?

Tags: java, android, navigationview

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51668942/3692177), I learned how to add extra views to the `NavigationView`'s menu items, by adding an `action layout`. My question is, essentially, how can I tweak each of those individual `actionLayout`s dynamically, through Java?

In my case, instead of adding a "switch" to the menu items, I used `actionLayout`s to add an extra icon that will show a state for that item. It's a boolean state, so I want to show the difference either by changing the extra icon dynamically or by toggling visibility.

So I have a `menu.xml` like this one for my `NavigationView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:id="@+id/menu_group"
        android:checkableBehavior="single" >
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_item1"
            android:icon="@drawable/some_main_icon"
            app:actionLayout="@layout/myflag_actionlayout"
            android:title="OPTION 1" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_item2"
            android:icon="@drawable/some_main_icon"
            app:actionLayout="@layout/myflag_actionlayout"
            android:title="OPTION 2" />
        <!-- etc. -->
    </group>
</menu>
```

...and my `myflag_actionlayout.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#444444"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/lockedIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_lock_idle_lock" />
</LinearLayout>
```

So it looks like this more or less:

[image: my_new_menu_items]

Now I wonder: how can I get each of those menu items' instances, access their `<ImageView>` instance from Java, and change each `lockedIcon`'s `ImageView` depending on a boolean variable? (For instance, toggling the `ImageView`'s visible attribute or changing the image for `app:srcCompat` attribute) Should I use some `findViewById(R.id.lockedIcon)` for this task, or is it a bad idea and I should do it another way?

##### EDIT:

Just now I recall, I already did something similar to access those "`NavigationView` items" by Java, and add a string to the counter editing the title:

```
NavigationView nav_v = findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
MenuItem nav_option1 = nav_v.getMenu().findItem(R.id.menu_item1);
nav_option1.setTitle(getString(R.string.nav_option1_title) + " -> " + some_counter);
```

Maybe i can from `nav_option1` invoke some method to access its action layout?

Comment: Even though I do not use Kotlin, I'm not too afraid of it. I could convert it to `Java` most probably anyway...

Comment: So if you know how to get a particular MenuItem, why aren't you using [`getActionView()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem#getActionView())?

Comment: @ianhanniballake because I just didn't knew it existed... let's try this out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good! @ianhanniballake 's suggested method worked like a charm. If I do this:

```
NavigationView nav_v = findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
MenuItem nav_option1 = nav_v.getMenu().findItem(R.id.menu_item1);
ImageView option1_lock_icon = nav_option1.getActionView().findViewById(R.id.lockedIcon);
```

And from there, I could do whatever I want with this `ImageView`:

```
// Toggle visibility approach
if (item_locked) {
    option1_lock_icon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    option1_lock_icon.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}

// Change icon approach
string uri = "";
if (item_locked) {
    uri = "@android:drawable/ic_lock_idle_lock";
} else {
    uri = "@android:drawable/ic_menu_view";
}
int imageResource = getResources()
      .getIdentifier(uri,
                     null,
                     getPackageName()
      );
option1_lock_icon.setImageDrawable(
       getResources().getDrawable(imageResource)
);
```

Also, it looks like I can do more or less the same with any object I add to those "action layouts". :-)

Comment: Would self-accepting my answer too soon be unfair? I wonder...