# How to add footer buttons in NavigationView

Tags: android, drawerlayout, navigationview

I'm following the post ["Android design library NavigationView with footer"](http://blog.nitish.io/post/122633295558/android-design-library-navigationview-with-footer) to add buttons at the bottom of NavigationView. The problem is that only the last NavigationView appears and it's occuping the entire screen height.

**Here is my layout:**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Activity here -->

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation_menu_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation_footer_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer_footer"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Here is the result:**

[image]

**How can i fix this?**

Comment: That blog is a few months old and the design support library has had a few updates in that time. In particular NavigationView now uses a RecyclerView internally instead of a ListView. It's possible that this trick just doesn't work anymore. Try it out using an older build of the library and see if that changes anything.

Comment: @Brucelet, do you known another solution?

Comment: Confirmed, on 23.0.1 this trick works, on 23.1 doesn't work

Comment: Any news on this? I also need a sticked footer with the support NavigationView!

Comment: I have answerd this with and easy example here http://stackoverflow.com/a/38476562/5817706

Answer (score 17):

The simplest answer is to add a button inside the Drawer layout and set it gravity to bottom in the navigationview.xml

as easy as that !!! here is the code.

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

   <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_sing_in"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="@string/sign_in"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
       />
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

[image: add button inside Drawer layour]

Comment: button is hiding the nagivation items

Comment: scroll up to see it

Comment: scrolling doesn't show it when the list item falls behind that view. This is not an option

Answer (score 12):

Weights and margins may need to be added or tweaked depending on how many items you want top and bottom, but this should be what you're looking for:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="10">

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer_bottom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_footer"  />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: You need to set `app:elevation=0dp` to the inner NavigationViews else the footer will have a strange gradient background. Unless there's a way to remove the scrolling effect of the footer, I stick to using simple TextViews in the footer. However, it's a good solution.